# Residue of $\frac{\sin z}{z^3(z-1)(z-3)}$ at zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How can I compute the residue of this function at zero:

$$\frac{\sin z}{z^3(z-1)(z-3)}$$

The pole is of order 2 (since there is a zero on the numerator of order 1). So I would tend to multiply by $z^2$ and then take the limit of the first derivative as $z$ tends to zero. This is not working however. Any suggestions?

Comment: The approach seems correct. You probably just made a small mistake in your calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Laurent series:
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{\sin z}{z^3(1-z)(3-z)}\\
&=\frac{1+z^2/6+\cdots}{z^2}\left(1+z+z^2+\cdots\right)
\left(\frac13+\frac{z}9+\frac{z^2}{27}+\cdots\right)
\end{align}
and all we need is to extract the $1/z$ coefficient.

Comment: When dealing with 3 sum multiplications what is a systematic way to find all the combinations? @Lord Shark the Unknown

Comment: @johnmelon: the residue is given by the coefficient of $z$ in the product $$(1+z+z^2+\ldots)\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{z}{9}+\ldots\right)$$ hence it equals $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}=\color{red}{\frac{4}{9}}$.

Comment: Why don't we care about the disk of convergence ? I.e we could expand in Laurent terms instead right ? Do we choose to expand in Taylor terms because it makes the calculation easier? Could we do both ?